# Arcpy script appearing in text format in arcgis 10.1 but in Idle (normal) format in arcgis 10

Tags: arcpy

I added my arcpy scripts in Arctoolbox.
But, when opening in edit view in Arctoolbox in Arcgis 10.1, they are opening in text format instead with Idle edition mode. That is not appearing in Arcgis 10.
I would like to have them opening in Idle edit mode in Arcgis 10.1.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To set the Python editor, from the Geoprocessing menu select Geoprocessing Options. In the Geoprocessing Options dialog, browse to the path where the desired editor executable file is located for Script Tool Editor/Debugger.

If you do not know the path to your Python editor, you can get it from the Windows Start Menu. The Start menu is nothing more than a collection of shortcuts to programs. You can get the location these shortcuts reference from the shortcut properties.

To find these paths, open the Start menu and right click on the program you prefer to use for script editing. Select properties and in the dialog select the Shortcut tab. In the shortcut tab, simply copy the target field. Use this path in ArcGIS as the location of both your script editor and debugger. With these properties set in ArcGIS for Desktop, you can seamlessly use any IDE you like for editing your scripts.

Borrowed from [here](http://joelmccune.com/specify-editor-for-python-scripts-in-arcgis-for-desktop/).

Answer (score 1):

Open IDLE and then go to File>Open>Browse to file.

By clicking edit it opens it in a text editor, like Notepad. You are still changing the file, but to run the file in IDLE, just do the following process above.

Or just follow these steps http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/40263

> - Open ArcMap or ArcCatalog.
> - Select Geoprocessing > Geoprocessing
>     Options. In the Editor\Debugger section, change the editor to
>     C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw